# Read ini files with Apache Ant

Tags: apache, ant, ini

Is there a way to read properties from an INI file with apache ant? I stumbled across apache-contrib's IniFile but it's sole purpose seems to edit and write INI files - not to simply read them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are "name=value" format with no sections (I'm not sure what Ant would do with sections), you can use this.

```
<property file="myinifile.ini"/>
```

Comment: sections are not supported by Ant [property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) task

Comment: Even though it seems that this answer helped - It does not answer the question, how to read ini-files with ant